# How to get checked combobox in dojo

Tags: javascript, combobox, dojo

I want to have a combobox, with a check box in front of each item,  where I could select multiple values.

Is there any..?? plz help

(I used Lovcombo in extjs, is there any widget similar to this?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `dojox.form.CheckedMultiSelect` which looks like:

[image]

and it has property `dropdown` - set it to `true` and you will get:

[image]

Unfortunately there is some styling issue or so as you cannot see which items are checked, but maybe you can fix it in no time.

Comment: yes, you can, but you have to wrap `dojo.store.*` into `dojo.data.ObjectStore` adapter, because `CheckedMultiSelect` has not been updated to use Dojo Object Store API. I put together an example for you at jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/894af/

Comment: Thanks phusick, but can I load the store using response like "checkedMultiselect.store.objectStore.data=response"?? I couldn't able to do so.. Is it because the label compulsory for the data field?? can't I have searchAttr: "userDefinedField"??

Comment: I do not have any experience with `CheckedMultiSelect`, but I took a look into its source code and I think I found a workaround how to accomplish what you need. I changed the jsFiddle accordingly: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/894af/

Comment: Yes..I tried changing the jsonObj inserting a new field ,"label". It seems that label is necessary for checkedMultiSelect to work. But I couldn't resolve the styling issue, which is "n item(s) selected".. could you please tell how to do that, separate items selected by some delimiter.. Sorry, I am new to JScripting..

Comment: I answered this in your latest question as it won't fit inside the comment.